# How to find all regular expression matches in the file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of regular expressions(about 2000) and over a million html files. I want to check if each regular expression success on every file or not. How to do this on powershell?

Performance is important, so I don't want to loop through regular expressions.

I try

```
$text | Select-String -Pattern pattern1, pattern2,...
```

And it returns all matches, but I also want to find out, which pattern success which one not. I need to build a list of success regular expressions for each file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$regex = "^test","e2$"  #Or use (Get-Content <path to your regex file>)
$ht = @{}

#Modify Get-Childitem to your criterias(filter, path, recurse etc.)
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern $regex | ForEach-Object { 
    $ht[$_.Path] += @($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Pattern)
}
```

Test-output:

```
$ht | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name                                               Value
----                                               -----
C:\Users\graimer\Desktop\New Text Document (2).txt {e2$}
C:\Users\graimer\Desktop\New Text Document.txt     {^test, e2$}
```

You didn't specify how you wanted the output.

UPDATE: To match multiple patterns on a single line, try this(mjolinor's answer is probably faster then this).

```
$regex = "^test","e2$"  #Or use (Get-Content <path to your regex file>)
$ht = @{}

#Modify Get-Childitem to your criterias(filter, path, recurse etc.)
$regex | ForEach-Object {
    $pattern = $_
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | ForEach-Object { 
        $ht[$_.Path] += @($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Pattern)
    }
}
```

UPDATE2: I don't have enough samples to try it, but since you have such a huge amount of files, you migh want to try reading the file into memory before looping through the patterns. It may be faster.

```
$regex = "^test","e2$"  #Or use (Get-Content <path to your regex file>)
$ht = @{}

#Modify Get-Childitem to your criterias(filter, path, recurse etc.)
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $text = $_ | Get-Content
    $filename = $_.FullName
    $regex | ForEach-Object {
        $text | Select-String -Pattern $_ | ForEach-Object { 
            $ht[$filename] += @($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Pattern)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it appears that if you have multiple patterns it will only return the first match it finds per line.  If a given line matches multiple regexes, it will only give you the first pattern it found that matched.

Comment: Updated answer. The fact that you could have multiple different matches on a single line wasn't clear in the question. The `-AllMatches` switch should have solved that, but it doesn't seem to work properly with an array of patterns. I will report it as a PowerShell bug / feature request.

Comment: I need multiple match on the same line, and yes -AllMatches doesn't work properly... thanks for hint

Comment: Seems the only way to process files, is to implement Aho-Corasick algorithm manually

Comment: Updated answer. Might be a faster solution considering the amount of files. You can see if it helps. :-).  If anyone agrees that the problem with the first sample is bug and are a member of connect, please vote up feedback `808786` on Micosoft Connect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way around doing a foreach through the regex collection.

This is the best I could come up with performance-wise:

```
$regexes = 'pattern1','pattern2'
$files = get-childitem -Path  <file path> |
 select -ExpandProperty fullname

$ht = @{}

 foreach ($file in $files)
 {
   $ht[$file] = New-Object collections.arraylist
   foreach ($regex in $regexes)
    {
      if (select-string $regex $file -Quiet)
        {
          [void]$ht[$file].add($regex)
        }
    }
}

$ht
```

You could speed up the process by using background jobs and dividing up the file collection among the jobs.